# Troubles renaming filenames with diacritics

Tags: regex, bash, diacritics, file-rename

Why does this bash command try to replace `é` with `ee` and not with `e`?

```
$ rename 's/[éè]/e/g' tést                
Can't rename tést teest: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

How may I get it work the way I'm expecting?

Comment: what would the error be in english? does it say the file does not exist? what would `ls tést` give in the current directory?

Comment: the double e thing probably has to do with the filename being UTF-8 so the accent character will be two bytes, which rename seems not to handle properly. sed would do for me: `echo  tést |sed  's/[éè]/e/g'` -> test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your terminal is set to UTF-8, but `rename` operates on bytes. Therefore, it in fact sees `s/[\303\251\303\250]/e/g`, and your string `t\303\251st` contains two of them, so each one is replaced by `e`.

You can add any Perl code to the expression, so you can turn utf-8 for the regular expression on by `use utf8` and you can decode the argument by decoding the topic variable `$_`:

```
rename 'use utf8; use Encode; $_ = decode("UTF-8", $_); s/[éè]/e/g' tést
```

Comment: Amazing, there always are new things to learn here. Thanks :)